# turning the corners of CGRect round like with UIView

Tags: uibezierpath, cgrect, uigraphicscontext

I have this function that basically adds a given text below a given image, I wish to make the corners of `textRect` round, can you help me understand how to use `UIBezierPath` in this code

```
-(UIImage*) overlapText:(NSString*) p_text inImage:(UIImage*) p_image atPoint:(CGPoint) p_point
{
    p_point.y += p_image.size.height-5;

    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(p_image.size.width+15,p_image.size.height+15));
    CGFloat imageX = (p_image.size.width+10)/2 - (p_image.size.width/2);
    [p_image drawInRect:CGRectMake(imageX,0,p_image.size.width,p_image.size.height)];

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(0, p_point.y, p_image.size.width+15, p_image.size.height+10);

    [[UIColor colorWithRed:(70/255.0) green:(70/255.0) blue:(70/255.0) alpha:1] set];
    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), textRect);


    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    [p_text drawInRect:textRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];


    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image context is the current context, so just construct the rounded rect with `bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cornerRadius:`, set your fill color, and tell the bezier path to `fill`. It's one line of code (well, two if you count setting the fill color):

```
[[UIColor colorWithRed:(70/255.0) green:(70/255.0) blue:(70/255.0) alpha:1] set];
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:textRect cornerRadius:5] fill];
```

Feel free to play with the numbers here; for example, you might like a different corner radius. Experiment!

Comment: can you please help me with the code? do I delete the CGRect?

Comment: A CGRect is just a path. I'm saying, use a different path. You are saying `CGContextFillRect`. That draws a filled rectangle. I'm suggesting that you draw a filled rounded rect instead.